# Chromedriver Browser Timeout Go Back to Previous Page Error - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Basically, I have created a program that sends a query to a search engine. From the results of the search, it will pick a random link to click on. This works. Now, I have set a timeout for 3 seconds for waiting. If the page takes longer than 3 seconds to load, I want to use a try/except block and catch the error/exception and just go back to the previous page.

I ran into a few issues. I've tried multiple methods, but I keep getting a second timeout error while in the current 'Except TimeoutException' state.

Here is the code from my most recent attempt:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.set_page_load_timeout(30) # Set to 2 seconds to raise timeoutexception

browser.get('http://bing.com')
time.sleep(2)

try:
    browser.set_page_load_timeout(2) #Set load to 2 sec to raise exception
    browser.get('http://amazon.com')
    print('Successfully opened page.')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Timeout Exception occurred.')
    browser.set_page_load_timeout(30) # Set to normal load timeout
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.execute_script('return window.stop')
    print('Browser loading stopped.')
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.execute_script('window.history.go(-1)')
    print('Browser successfully went back to the previous page.')
```

This raises a second timeout when trying to do anything with the browser. For the 'return window.stop' I have tried:

```
browser.execute_script('return window.stop')
browser.execute_script('return window.stop()')
browser.execute_script('window.stop')
browser.execute_script('window.stop()')
browser.execute_script('window.stop()';)
browser.execute_script('return window.stop';) etc.etc.
```

I have also tried `browser.back()` method to go back in the browser. I'm at a loss here. Anyone have a workaround?

Please let me know if you need additional information. I just made some sample code here testing by going to Bing then straight to Amazon.

Comment: I think there is some issue with the set_page_load_timeout, I am having the same issue, once the exception is triggered control is not returned. You can use webdriver.Firefox(timeout=5) and that works for me, python 3.6, selenium, 3.5. set_page_load_timeout seems to work for Phantom but not Chrome Driver 2.31.

Comment: What OS are you on? What Chrome Driver Version are you using?

Comment: I'm writing this for Linux Ubuntu 16.04 Server, but I'm currently testing it on Windows 7. 

Chromedriver 2.31, Selenium 3.5, Python 3.5.2

The only reason I would like to keep ChromeDriver 2.31 is that it includes the send_keys fix that allows headless use.

I do have a modified 2.30 version for Linux that also has the send_keys fix. Maybe that would work...

Comment: Actually I don't a different version of chromedriver solved things for me either. Although I ran your code with my set-up and it worked, on both versions so not really sure. Sorry :(

Comment: Did you get the timeout exception when you ran it? If not, maybe lower the timeout to 1 second. 

Also, it goes through the timeout exception sometimes. But my script will run daily and I cannot have it error out.

What OS are you using?

Comment: I am on macOS, I not able to re-produce your error even at timeout of 0.1 sec, the error is caught and then the other functions are executed. Sorry don't know if I can help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Hmm. Can you tell me the Chrome Browser version and selenium version you're using? Maybe I can try that combo on linux/windows/mac and see if it works

Comment: Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit), Selenium 3.5.0

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do. I have selenium 3.5 on windows/linux and chrome Version 60.0.3112.101 on windows and chrome 61.0.3124.4 on linux.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is an equivalent of "webdriver.Firefox(timeout=5)" for chromedriver?

Comment: Not that I know of unfortunately, did you try Firefox?